# onExpose function deprecated

Tags: haskell, events, gtk, gtk2hs

I'm using Gtk2Hs to build a GUI drawing some picture in a window. I use the function `onExpose` to connect the expose event to the redrawing function.

```
onExpose canvas $ \_ -> do
    refreshArea canvas ... 
    return True
```

Things are working but in reading the Gtk2Hs documentation, I saw that this function is deprecated and will disappear in next version of Gtk2Hs.

**Do you know how to replace the `onExpose` function to connect the expose event to my funtion for a long time compatibility?**

Comment: Could you please provide a link to documentation where it is marked as deprecated? `onExpose` lives in `gtk` package, but `gtk3` uses `exposeEvent` instead. I don't see any deprecation notice in docs.

Comment: the link is : https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.2/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#v:onExpose

Comment: Ah, the whole section is deprecated, I never noticed that. Usually the `DEPRECATED` pragma is used for that. Anyway, `exposeEvent` is the way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use [new event handling API](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.2/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Gdk-EventM.html#t:EventM). In particular you should install a handler for [`exposeEvent`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/gtk-0.14.2/docs/Graphics-UI-Gtk-Abstract-Widget.html#v:exposeEvent), like the next:

```
on canvas exposeEvent $ do
  -- do rendering here...
  return True
```

The same API is provided both by `gtk` and `gtk3` packages.